# Is it permitted to run a gas pipe through the now unused chimney to get to the attic and from there to the other side of the house?

Tags: pipe, natural-gas

This is about a bungalow, the width of the house is 25'
My furnace and the gas pipe that feeds this is in the basement.
I would like to run the gas pipe through that chimney all the way to the attic and at that elevation I would go across the house to reach the attached garage area where I would like to connect a natural gas heater

Is this something that is generally permitted ?

The pipe type I want to use is called tracpipe
https://tracpipe.ca/wp-content/uploads/FGP_001_DI_Guide.pdf

Comment: On the surface that just sounds like a  bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In your title, you say "unused"; then...

> My furnace and the gas pipe that feeds this is in the basement. I
>   would like to rung the gas pipe through **that** furnace...

So which is it? The furnace chimney that you are using for the furnace now, or an old furnace chimney that is now unused? Because if it is an old unused chimney, that can now become a "chase" from the basement to the attic and is perfectly legit. But if it is the chimney FOR your existing furnace, then no, you cannot use that for anything else.

Comment: the existing furnace does not use a chimney is a direct vent outside a feet or two above the ground. I fixed the typo there and I thought it is implied that the new furnaces do not use the chimney anymore but..that can be true just in my area with houses as old as mine

Answer (score 0):

from the data sheet:

> 4. In all locations, CSST must be supported in accordance with the manufacturer’s instructions (every 4 feet-3/8 size, 6 feet-1/2 size, 8 feet-3/4 size and 1 inch size) Support should be with metal EMT conduit straps or two-point attachment plastic clips suitable for the size of the tubing.

That seems like a deal breaker to me, but maybe you could run a vertical catenary, or get a crane to install a rigid structure with the pipe pre-arttached into the ex-chimney

Comment: does not sound reasonable to me as the chimney itself is a sort for pipe (not a brick one but enclosed in brick)